# Why we should use tsx instead of simple .js in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I was wondering that people were using `.tsx` file format in their `react-native project`. What's the `difference` between these 2 files format .tsx and .js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TSX is the extension one should use to use JSX with typescript.

Quoting the TS docs here..

> JSX is an embeddable XML-like syntax. It is meant to be transformed
> into valid JavaScript, though the semantics of that transformation are
> implementation-specific. JSX rose to popularity with the React
> framework, but has since seen other implementations as well.
> TypeScript supports embedding, type checking, and compiling JSX
> directly to JavaScript. Basic usage
>
> In order to use JSX you must do two things.
>
> ```
> Name your files with a .tsx extension
> Enable the jsx option
> ```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html

If you are using JSX with JavaScript you could use either .JS or .JSX it is upto you.